# jQuery Mobile: Sending data from one page to the another

Tags: php, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

i have a problem, i need to send data (an id) from a list to another page.
this is the html code:

```
</head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Players App</h1>
            </div><!--/header-->
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" id="ul_list" data-inset="true">

                </ul>
            </div><!--/content-->
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Players list</h4>
            </div><!--/footer-->
        </div><!--/page-index-->
        <div data-role="page" id="detail" data-add-back-btn="true">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Player detail</h1>
            </div><!--/header-->
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" id = "" data-inset="true">

                </ul>
            </div><!--/content-->
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Players list</h4>
            </div><!--/footer-->
        </div><!--/page-detail-->
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the script:

```
var lista = new Array();
var squadraManager={};

squadraManager.initArray=null;
squadraManager.printArray=null;

squadraManager.initArray = function(){
        lista[0] = new players();
        lista[0].setNome("Nonho");
        lista[0].setRuolo("difensore");
        lista[0].setCognome("Rossi");
        lista[0].setNMaglia("01");
        lista[1] = new players();
        lista[1].setNome("Marco");
        lista[1].setRuolo("blabla");
        lista[1].setCognome("Mariani");
        lista[1].setNMaglia("22");
        lista[2] = new players();
        lista[2].setNome("Carlo");
        lista[2].setRuolo("Soffiatore");
        lista[2].setCognome("Bianchi");
        lista[2].setNMaglia("01");
}
squadraManager.loaderList = function(){
    jQuery.each( lista, function(chiave, oggetto){
        //leggo valori oggetti in array 
            jQuery("#ul_list").append("<li><a id='"+ oggetto.getId() +"det' href='#dettaglio'>"+oggetto.getCognome()+"</a></li>").listview("refresh");
    });
}


squadraManager.init = function(){                             /*init */
    squadraManager.initArray();
    squadraManager.loaderList();
}
jQuery(function(){
    squadraManager.init();
});
```

i neet to send the id of the clicked list to the next page.
the final idea is to load in the second page "#detail" the detail of the player (the player is in a separate class).

Thank for the response

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### One HTML / multiple pages template

Here's an example of passing an attribute from listview to the second page in 1 html multi page template:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Gv7UW/ - js object as a storage container

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/J9NTr/ - localStorage as a storage container

Basically what you want to do is create a persistent javascript object for a storage purpose. As long ajax is used for page loading (and page is not reloaded in any way) that object will stay active.

```
    var storeObject = {
        firstname : '',
        lastname : ''
    }
```

### Multiple HTML pages template

Unfortunately this example can't be done through jsFiddle so I will post needed files:

**HTML 1 :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="operations.js"></script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" id="test-listview">
                <li><a href="page2.html?id=1">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html?id=2">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html?id=3">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html?id=4">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html?id=5">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML 2 :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**operations.js :**

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#second', function(){   
    alert(getParameterByName("id"));
}); 
     

function getParameterByName(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

### User authentication demo

Another example that can't be shown with a jsFiddle example, unlike previous one, this one will have attached SQL script. I would advise you to create a better db reading logic, this one is a simple solution, prone to SQL injection, but it will work well for your assignment:

**index.php :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <style>
        #login-button {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }        
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="login">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>Login Page</h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <label for="username">Enter your username:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
            <label for="password">Enter your password:</label>
            <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"/>  
            <a data-role="button" id="login-button" data-theme="b">Login</a>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3></h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            Here goes content
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>Page footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**json.php :**

```
<?php
    $var1 = $_REQUEST['action']; // We dont need action for this tutorial, but in a complex code you need a way to determine ajax action nature
    $jsonObject = json_decode($_REQUEST['outputJSON']); // Decode JSON object into readable PHP object
    
    $username = $jsonObject->{'username'}; // Get username from object
    $password = $jsonObject->{'password'}; // Get password from object
    
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  // Conect to mysql, first parameter is location, second is mysql username and a third one is a mysql password
    @mysql_select_db("test") or die( "Unable to select database"); // Connect to database called test
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$username."' and user_pass = '".$password."'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);

    if($num != 0) {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";        
    }
?>
```

**custom.js :**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#login', function(){ 
    $('#login-button').on('click', function(){
        if($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0){
            userObject.username = $('#username').val(); // Put username into the object
            userObject.password = $('#password').val(); // Put password into the object
            // Convert an userObject to a JSON string representation
            var outputJSON = JSON.stringify(userObject);
            // Send data to server through ajax call
            // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
            ajax.sendRequest({action : 'login', outputJSON : outputJSON});
        } else {
            alert('Please fill all nececery fields');
        }
    });    
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    if(userObject.username.length == 0){ // If username is not set (lets say after force page refresh) get us back to the login page
        $.mobile.changePage( "#login", { transition: "slide"} ); // In case result is true change page to Index  
    }
    $(this).find('[data-role="header"] h3').append('Wellcome ' + userObject.username); // Change header with wellcome msg
    //$("#index").trigger('pagecreate');
});

// This will be an ajax function set
var ajax = {
    sendRequest:function(save_data){
        $.ajax({url: 'http://localhost/JSONP_Tutorial/json.php',
            data: save_data,
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function() {
                // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
            },
            complete: function() {
                // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if(result == "true") {
                    $.mobile.changePage( "#index", { transition: "slide"} ); // In case result is true change page to Index
                } else {
                    alert('Login unsuccessful, please try again!'); // In case result is false throw an error
                }
                // This callback function will trigger on successful action
            },
            error: function (request,error) {
                // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
                alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
            }
        });
    }
}

// We will use this object to store username and password before we serialize it and send to server. This part can be done in numerous ways but I like this approach because it is simple
var userObject = {
    username : "",
    password : ""
}
```

**localhost.sql :**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.10.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Feb 02, 2013 at 11:58 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.20
-- PHP Version: 5.3.10

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `test`
--
CREATE DATABASE `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `test`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `user_pass` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `user_name`, `user_pass`) VALUES
(1, 'gajotres', 'testpass');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

More info

If you want to learn more about this topic take a look at this [article](http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/). You will find several solutions with examples.

Comment: Tnks, your answer was timely.

Comment: @Gajo : in short, in your [localStorage as storage version](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/J9NTr/) , the buttons toward different pages fire a function which set the localStorage to a new value. Sweet, I will reuse that :]