# Pass data from list view page to detail view page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jsonp, jquery-mobile-listview

I am generating the list view via ajax. What i am trying to do is when user click it takes it to details view through its id. I am getting the list but not the details.My question is how to pass the id from page to another page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var output = $('#output');
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost/Backend/getDinner.php',
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
timeout: 5000,
success: function(data, status){
$.each(data, function(i,item){ 
    var Menu_Dinner = '<li><a data-transition="slide" href="details.html?ID=' 
    + item.ID + '">' +`'<img src="'+ item.ImageURL + '">' +
    '<h2 class="ui-li-heading">' + item.Title + '</h2 >' + 
    '<h2>' + 'Price: ' + item.Price + '</h2>'+ '</a></li>';
    output.append(Menu_Dinner);
    console.log($("#output").html());`
});
},
error: function(){
  output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
}
});
});
```

i used the code below to get the id from list view and display details of that specific list.

```
$('#detailsPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
var ID = getUrlVars()["ID"];
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getDinner.php?ID='+ID, displayItem);
});  
function displayItem(data) {
var item = data.item;
console.log(item);
$('#itemPic').attr('src', '' + item.ImageURL);
$('#fTitle').text(item.Title);
$('#Description').text(item.Description);
$('#Price').text(item.Price);
}
```

And this is the detail.html page that display the details .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="detailsPage" data-role="page" >

<div data-role="header">
       <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="b">Back</a>
    <h1>Details</h1>
</div>

    <div data-role="content"> 

  <img id="itemPic"/>
  <h3 id="Title"></h3>
      <p id="Description"></p>
      <p id="Price"></p>


      <button class="add-to-cart">+ Add to Cart</button>
</div>

  </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help you, it is my answer/article about this topic: [jQuery Mobile: Sending data from one page to the another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776387/jquery-mobile-sending-data-from-one-page-to-the-another/14776523#14776523)

There you will find several solution, you just need to pick the right one.

One more thing, in case you want to stick to your solution you will need a way to store data during the page transition, my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)** can help you with that. Just search for the chapter called: **Data/Parameters manipulation between page transitions**.

Comment: Still the code is not working. Is something wrong with the code.   $('#detailsPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
var ID = getUrlVars()["ID"];
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getDinner.php?ID='+ID, displayItem);
});  
function displayItem(data) {
var item = data.item;
console.log(item);
$('#itemPic').attr('src', '' + item.ImageURL);
$('#fTitle').text(item.Title);
$('#Description').text(item.Description);
$('#Price').text(item.Price);
}

Comment: Method you are using will only work on multiple HTML jQuery Mobile template, check it. Also there are 4 available solutions, don't tell me you can't find a workable one.

Comment: Finally found the solution. Hope this would be helpful for someone in the future. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/rfF3j/1/