# jQuery Mobile Query Parameter test different between versions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, query-string

I am trying to use jQuery Mobile with query string parameters.

I have two test pagesbelow, one which works, one which doesn't.

The only difference between the two pages is the version of jQuery Mobile and jQuery. Check out the URL difference between "working" and "not working". How can I get the URL to remain intact in the latest version of jQuery Mobile? What would have changed to prevent this?

Thanks!

http://andrewherrick.com/spike/jquery_mobile_param/test_param_working.html

http://andrewherrick.com/spike/jquery_mobile_param/test_param_not_working.html

Comment: How is this too localized? I think passing parameters in the query string with jQuery Mobile is something a lot of people would want to do

Comment: Both of them are working correctly in Firefox.

Comment: in the "not working" version it strips off the query string. same with Firefox I just checked

Comment: I can see that. Funny Chrome version is also working for my. Both pages are trowing alerts.

Comment: Yea they throw the alert, its just the query string is gone with the latest version of jQ mobile. (1.3.1)

Comment: jQm v1.3.1: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/faq/pass-via-the-hash-to-page.html

Comment: Why does it matter if parameter can't be seen? They are still passing successfully.

Comment: think about for copying and pasting that URL to someone else, deep linking

Comment: @Omar so they must have removed this ability?

Comment: it seems so, because on v 1.2.0 it was available. check last 3 paraghraphs. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Comment: that's ridiculous, how would you get deep linking then in a jQuery mobile app

Comment: @Gajotres has a nice tutorial on passing parameters without the need to use any plugin/add-on.

Comment: where is this tutorial?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776387/jquery-mobile-sending-data-from-one-page-to-the-another/14776523#14776523

Comment: Any work around or way to force the url params to stay in the URL?

Comment: @Halsafar my new [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) solves your problem I believe

Comment: @aherrick if you are still looking for answers, please see my previous comment and hope it helps!