# How to cancel previous page's pageshow event when user press back button on current page in phonegap ios

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing one app that uses iScroller to display list of products,

I have used the pageshow event for loading the list of product, due to some circumstances i am not able to use the `pageinit()`.

Issue is that when i click on any product it shows product detail page, but on product detail page when i click on back button, it again call the `pageshow()` of the product list page.

I dont want to run the `pageshow()` when user clicks on back button on detail page, other then this back button i want to run the `pageshow()` from everywhere else.

Please tell me how to solve this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The below example uses a *variable* to check whether *back-button* was clicked to view `#products` page. Once user navigate to from `#products` to `#details` and back using *back-button* it will alert that `#products` was viewed and thus you can stop reloading data again.

However, if a user navigate to other pages and back to `#products` page, it will work normally as it hasn't been viewed.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DfAN2/)**

```
var viewed = false;

$(document).on('click', '.backbtn', function () {
 viewed = true;
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#products', function () {
 if (viewed) {
  alert('page has been viewed');
  viewed = false;
 }
 else {
  alert('first visit!');
 }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but this solution works when we use single HTML file for two DIVs that are page, but when i create two HTML file separately then it want work.

Comment: then you need to pass parameters between pages, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776387/jquery-mobile-sending-data-from-one-page-to-the-another/14776523#14776523 @NiravLimbasiya