# JQuery AJAX Get data from database and feed it to HTML?

Tags: jquery

I want to use database data and send it to a PHP script using JQuery's AJAX. How would I achieve this?

Here's the code so far:

```
function update(id) {
  $("#update").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?= base_url("event/update_event_view"); ?>',
      data: {'id': id},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(retval) {
        $('#display').hide();
        $('#up').show();
        $('#up').html(retval[0]);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: i think you are on right track this is the way to do

Comment: Show us your problem or error you are facing.

Comment: This question was already answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776387/jquery-mobile-sending-data-from-one-page-to-the-another

Comment: u have a typo in ur `php tag`. `<?php base_url(); ?>`

Comment: @rockStar `<?=` is shorthand of `<?php`.

Comment: @Shadow show us your `retval`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
function update(id) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "@Url.Action("update_event_view", "event")",
          data: {'id': id},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(retval) {
                 $('#display').hide();
                 $('#up').show();
                 $('#up').html(retval);
           }
      });
 }
```

Comment: OP needs answer in `PHP` not `.Net`.

Comment: thanks rohan....now if my script is fine then how to use those array of retVal in html page in table???